# How to setup Git-plus in Atom to work with Github

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

On Windows, I installed the [`git-plus package`](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus) in Atom by installing it from Atom main menu `File` → `Settings` → `Install`.  Using `git config`, I then configured `user.email` and `user.name` and made sure that they reflect my account and email address in Github.

I then followed the instructions, [from the GitHub site](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), I generated new pair of ssh keys. I made sure that there is only one pair of keys on my system. Now with `git-plus` and the ssh keys configured, how do I go about start working on files on my Github repository?

Comment: Do you already have a repository checked out?

Comment: I also face the issue on Win10. My MSYS2 environment knows my ssh key, but Atom (outside MSYS2) doesn't. So I push/pull via shell.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the steps below and it seems to be working fine.

- Clone your GitHub repository using SSH, such as, 
  git clone @github.com:.git
  Note, if you perform clone from Git Bash for the first time, host, github.com, will be added into file, KNOWN_HOST, which on Windows, it is in .ssh
  The command creates a local copy of original/master from your GitHub
- Add the local copy of your repository to Atom. From Atom menu, File > Add Project Folder…
- Verify that you can work with your GitHub repository, e.g., performing pull.
  In Atom, open Git command line, Ctrl+Shift+H, and type in pull, then from the available branch list choose > original/master